# converting greyscale image from RGB to YUV gives non-zero U and V

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

I've read that if image is **greyscale** then it shouldn't have **B** and **R** component in **RGB** and no **U** and **V** in **YUV** color spaces. 
Does it mean they should be equal to 0?

I'm using this code to get YUV values:

```
var px = (this.canvas.Image as Bitmap).GetPixel(i, j);

var y = 0.299 * px.R + 0.587 * px.G + 0.114 * px.B;
var u = -0.14713 * px.R - 0.28886 * px.G + 0.436 * px.B;
var v = 0.615 * px.R - 0.51499 * px.G - 0.10001 * px.B;
```

And I'm getting non-zero **u** and **v** values, though they're are close to 0. Should I convert them to **int** anyway? Was the image really greyscale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion from RBG to YUV uses multiplication with floating point values. *Both* floating point multiplication *and* the formulas you use are approximative, thus it is not strange that the resulting values are not exactly 0 *even if* it was a greyscale image. It is probably safe to set **u** and **v** to 0 if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your input image is given in color space RGB (red-green-blue), then all three components should have the same value on every pixel. If this is not the case (you may or may not want to neglect small differences though) for your image, then it is not really gray-scale. The RGB has three truly colored components.

On the other hand, the YUV color space has one luma (or brightness) channel, which is the Y-component, and 2 chrominance chanels (U- and V-components).

The Y is built from the RGB-components by a weighted average, see your code calculating the y. However, the green component gets more weight in order to resemble the sensitivity of the human eye. The three coeeficients sum up to 1.0 and are all positive, thus they are computing a linear combination similar to an average.

But the 3 coefficients for computing the U-components (most sensitive to blueish colors) all sum up to 0.0. (same for the V-component, which is most sensitve to redish colors). Therefore, assuming you put in a truely gray-scaled RGB-image, the resulting U and V would be 0.0.

If that is not the case (assume very small values to simply be noisy variants of 0), then again, your input RGB-image was not truely a gray-scaled image.